# How do I check authentication while searching local media servers via libvlc or libvlcsharp

Tags: authentication, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm now testing the local network feature of libvlcsharp.

I've checked the example [here](https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/LocalNetwork) worked fine when listing different servers in the local network.

But I don't know if I missed something when opening some SMB servers that need certain authentications. They just showed empty folders and I didn't find any entry to provide the username or password information.

Are there some other examples that can show me the authentication part of libvlc or libvlcsharp? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) that you can pass options specifically made for smb authentication, namely `--smb-user`, `--smb-pwd` and `--smb-domain`. You can pass them at the libvlc creation, or as media options (which sounds more logical) as `:smb-user`, `:smb-pwd` and `:smb-domain` respectively.

If your login is interactive (shows a prompt when you open it with libvlc), you can also use the Dialog API. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65677758/2663813) for an example

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this demo sooner or later. By the way, is there a way to check if an SMB server really needs the authentication if listing items failed?

Comment: Thanks to @cube45. Though I mistook the question, it's working when requesting the local network videos.